# Is there a hook available when creating a tag in Subversion?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, tagging, svn-hooks

I think the question explains it all, but let me explain what I want to do.

I am playing around with the idea of whenever a tag is created in my repo, all the commit messages entered since the previous tag are entered into a wiki page.  That way, people do not need access to the subversion server to see what commits were made for each tag.

Perhaps there is an easier way, but I was thinking that I could do it by wiring in a hook for tag creation.  Thoughts?  Advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no operation "tag creation" for svn, all folders' names such as *tags*, *trunk*, etc - are just convention on standard SVN repository layout. What you call "tag creation" is in truth - a creation of a new svn location (which is specially known on a server side as copied from another location). All operations on files - uploading changes, adding new files, deletion, even changing svn properties - are commit operations. That is why what you need is to write a script and set it as [a pre-commit or post-commit hook on SVN server](http://www.grepmymind.com/2009/03/07/svn-pre-commit-post-commit-hooks/).

According to your well described task I can give an idea on how I see the implementation.
This script should check the path being commited (or after) whether it looks like 
`some_svn_path/tags/tag_name`
, then find the previous tag in this folder 
`some_svn_path/tags/tag_name_prev` 
and get the svn revision of it, then get the original path from current transaction (path from which this tag is copied from), probably 
`some_svn_path/trunk`
, and finally get log messages from original svn path from revision of the previous tag till the current revision.